# Target wpcf7submit event for specific Post Id

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

With the help of wordpress contact form 7 and popupmaker plugin for contact form in popup.
I would like user to first fill out a form, and after successful submission pdf will download. I am using javascript to target "wpcf7submit" event and one hidden field in contact-form having pdf with below wordpress action hook:

```
function case_study_download(){ ?>
<script>
document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event){
    if('6980'== event.detail.contactFormId){
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    var urs = inputs[6].value;
    window.location.href=urs;
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
    }, 3000);
}
}, false);
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'case_study_download');
```

Using above code I can able to download pdf after submission of contact form 7 form. And I am using popup-maker plugin to open contact form on-click.

This all work fine, however I have displayed multiple post with pdf links on the same page, for that I am also passing post-id in the above condition using "detail.containerPostId" custom event but I didn't get any pdf after form submission.
Refer below:

```
function case_study_download(){ ?>
<script>
document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function(event){
    if('6980'== event.detail.contactFormId && '345'== event.detail.containerPostId){
    var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
    var urs = inputs[6].value;
    window.location.href=urs;
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();
    }, 3000);
}
}, false);
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'case_study_download');
```

Please advice me, Is it a right way to pass post-id in the above condition?
Because, I want to download a specific pdf by post-id with the same contact-form-id (or multiple).

Comment: The container post ID is a form field `_wpcf7_container_post`

Comment: Actually, When I add one form in single page and test by using post-id, it's working well. But I am adding contact-form 7 shortcode in popup maker and I have passed the popup-maker class on other page (where I want popup form on-click). May be that reason the post-id doesn't match. So what can I do in this case?  did you understand my query?

Comment: You're going to have to pass a variable with the parent post ID in a hidden form field. However, I'm not sure how the popup maker adds items to the post itself. So `get_the_ID()` probably won't work either. I don't use plugins to make modals, I just use jquery and bootstrap modals when I do something like this.

Comment: Thanks Howard, I need to try some other stuffs for popup model instead of popup plugin.